# Why doesn't my speech recognition platform open up Wikipedia via the query?

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm building weak AI platform like Siri, however, every time I run the code I receive "if 'wikipedia' in query():
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" instead of it opening up Wikipedia.Can someone please walk me through fixing this. Thanks

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os
import smtplib
import pythoncom

print("Initializing Assistant...")

MASTER = "Bob"

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)


def speak(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def wishMe():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)

    if hour >= 0 and hour < 12:
        speak("Good Morning" + MASTER)

    elif hour >= 12 and hour < 18:
        speak("Good Afternoon" + MASTER)
    else:
        speak("Good Evening" + MASTER)

   # speak("I am Karren. How may I assist you?")


def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-uk')
        print(f"user said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Sorry i didn't catch that...")


speak("Initializing Assistant...")
wishMe()
query = takeCommand()

# Logic
if 'wikipedia' in query:
    speak('searching wikipedia...')
    query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
    results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=2)
```

Comment: `takeCommand` doesn't return anything, so the check is essentially `if 'wikipedia' in None`, which is not valid. You probably want to return `query` from that function. You will need to handle the case where the speech recognition failed.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `takeCommand` doesn't return anything, which means that it explicitly returns `None`. Hence, the line

```
if 'wikipedia' in query:
```

is equivalent to

```
if 'wikipedia' in None:
```

which is not valid and will raise `TypeError`.

Instead, you probably want to return `query` from `takeCommand`, subject to the successful speech recognition, i.e.:

```
def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        audio = r.listen(source)

    query = None
    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-uk')
        print(f"user said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Sorry i didn't catch that...")

    return query
```

Then, you may check that you have a valid return value before treating it as a string:

```
query = takeCommand()

if query is None:
    # Report to user that their speech was not understood
    ...
else:
    # Process query
    if 'wikipedia' in query:
        # Do something with query
        ...
```